# Put k stones on a n * m grid, to maximize the number of rectangles for which there is one stone in each corner

Tags: algorithm, math, combinatorics

Put k stones on a n * m grid, each stone should be on an intersection point of the lines of grid.Try to find a way to put the stones, in order to maximize the number of rectangles for which there is one stone in each corner. Output the number.

for example, if k <= 3, the answer is 0, meaning no such rectangle; if k is 4 and n, m >= 2, the answer is 1; more examples:

(n, m, k, answer): (3, 3, 8, 5), (4, 5, 13, 18), (7, 14, 86, 1398)
[image: red circles are stones]
[image]

k is between 0 and n * m.
n, m are positive integers less than 30000

ps:This is actually a problem in Microsoft-Beauty-of-Programming qualification round(But you may not be able to find it since it is held in China and I translate it to English myself.)
pss:I have made some progress. It can be proved that to get the answer, searching through all possible Ferrers diagrams is enough, but the complexity is exponential with regard to k.

**EDIT:** (by Dukeling)

A visualization of (3, 3, 8, 5), with the rectangles indicated in different colours.

[image: Grid]

As you noticed, it's actually a (n-1) * (m-1) grid, there's another interpretation using a n * m grid where the stones are placed inside the cells, but then you'll need to add an additional constraint that rectangles can't be width / height 1.

Comment: I don't really understand how you got those answers. Can you explain exactly where you place the stones and why you get that many rectangles? What is "a conjunction of the grid"?

Comment: @IVlad I made an edit which should make things clearer.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered the densest case, i.e. computed the number of rectangles for a full m*n grid with stones at every crossing? How many rects do you get when you remove one of these stones? Does it matter which one you remove? What would be a good choice to remove a seconds stone? How about a third? Does removing two stones together suggest a different set of stones than when you remove first one and then the other? Can you detect a pattern? Can you describe it? Can you show that it is indeed optimal? This might be better posted at the Math SE, due to MathJax typesetting.

Answer (score 0):

From a programming perspective this suggests a search that takes advantage of the symmetries of the rectangle to reduce search space.  What follows is something of an extended hint.

As the OP points out, a naive implementation would check all possible k-subsets of nodes, a size of C(nm,k).

The amount of search space reduction depends on how symmetries are exploited.  The square has symmetries of reflection and rotation, so for n=m there's an 8-fold symmetry group.  If say n < m, then the lesser amount of symmetry gives a 4-fold group.

A typical approach is to organize the possible k-subsets by a lexicographic ordering, so that a potential configuration is skipped when it's equivalent to one of earlier appearance in that ordering.

But there are additional "wrap-around" symmetries to be exploited.  Suppose the last row of the grid is moved to the top (along with any assignment of stones to its nodes).  This transformation preserves the count of the 4-stone rectangles (though the exact sizes of those rectangles will differ).

Indeed transposing two rows or two columns preserves the counts of 4-stone rectangles.  Once you have that insight, can you see how to parameterize the search space more efficiently?

**Added:**  Even though it's more of a math insight than programming, consider the number of 4-stone rectangles provided by a "full subrectangle", say r x c if rc < k.  Consider the incremental number of extra rectangles provided by one more stone; by two more stones.